# pygame download fo python 3.5

Tags: python, installation, pygame, python-3.5

I am running python 3.5 and I want to install pygame, the website only supports up to version 3.2. I have tried a few forums on this and other websites but they are all for python 3.4. Does anyone know were I can i find the install file for python 3.5 and how to install it?

Thanks for your time

Comment: This is not an appropriate place to ask such a question. It is off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Questions asking us to **recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource** are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393) and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[This link](https://skellykiernan.wordpress.com/2015/01/04/python-pygame-install/) says it's for Python 3.4, but at least [one user](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/109007) got it to work with 3.5.

You should download the wheel file called [pygame-1.9.2a0-cp35-none-win32.whl](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pygame) from here and use it instead of the "pygame-1.9.2a0-cp34-none-win32.whl" file he's using in the tutorial.